# Add value to the front of hash and mutate

Tags: ruby, hash, mutation

i want to add a value to the front of a hash and i want the hash to mutate.

Like so:

```
def put!(q,v)
  q = {:value => v, :next => q}
end
```

But this doesn't work because i can't assign q a new value like this.

How would i do this?

Thanks in advance for all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the `:next` key should have the image of the hash before modification.  You can do this...

```
def put!(q,v)
  q[:value], q[:next] = v, q.dup
end
```

the hash refrenced as `q` will be mutated so other references to the hash will reflect the change.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you'd ever want to do this, but here's a way to prepend a key & value pair to your hash :

```
hash = {b: 2, c: 3}
hash_copy = hash.dup
hash.clear
hash[:a] = 1
hash_copy.each do |k,v|
  hash[k] = v
end
p hash
# {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
```

It's slow and kinda useless: you need to duplicate your hash, remove all the keys, add one pair, and put all the pairs back.

The usual way would be to not care about the order :

```
hash = {b: 2, c: 3}
hash[:a] = 1
p hash
# {:b=>2, :c=>3, :a=>1}
```